# How to retrieve the class attributes from a list of class object

Tags: python, class

I have imported the nba dataset into a variable named nba.

these are my classes:

```
class Player():
        def __init__(self, data_row):
            self.player_name = data_row[0]

class team():
    def __init__(self,team_name):
        self.team_name = team_name
        self.roaster = []
        for x in nba:
            if x[3]==self.team_name:
                self.roaster.append(Player(x))
```

what i want is to store each player of a team to a team object.

```
spurs = team("TOT")
```

but when I run the code, I get a list of class objects as following:

```
print(spurs.roaster)
[<__main__.Player at 0x2211b2d06a0>,
 <__main__.Player at 0x2211b2d06d8>,
 <__main__.Player at 0x2211b2d0630>,
 <__main__.Player at 0x2211b2d0588>,]
```

how can I retrieve the objects attribute? I have tried:

```
spurs.roaster.player_name
```

but it came up with an error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'player_name'
```

Comment: Have to tried converting it to list. I mean just use list(spurs.roaster) and check your answer.

Comment: `roaster` is a list that contains many players. What do you expect `roaster.player_name` to return? How should it know what player you are interested in?

Comment: Do you know how to access elements of a list? If yes, the problem is 33% solved. Do you know how to iterate over lists? You do. 66% done. Do you know how to construct new lists? If yes, you're done. Here I assume you need a list of attributes.

Comment: It is already a list. I don't want to iterate throught the list.I wanna get the player names that are in the list by one lien of code.

Comment: spurs.roaster[0].player_name   this one gives me the first player name. i want all players name of a team class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to see human readable implatation of Player, you should implement __ str __ method, for instance:

   ```
   class Player():
       def __init__(self, data_row):
           self.player_name = data_row[0]

       def __str__(self):
           return self.player_name
   ```

Your team.roaster attr is a list, so you can`t access it by key, you should either change it to dict or just iterate over it:

```
for roaster in spurs.roaster:
    print(roaster.player_name)
```

Comment: I see. so there is no simpler way to get the players name of a team.

Comment: tnx pal.I'll go with the loop then.

Answer (score 1):

The error you get is kind of self explainatory, `spurs.roaster` is indeed a list. The `player_name` attribute belongs to item within this list.
To acces theses attributes you'll have to go through your list.

```
for player in spurs.roaster:
    print(player.player_name)
```